# How to add an inherit QGraphicsEllipseItem to QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt

I added multiple ellipses to my QGraphicsScene:

```
QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse;
ellipse = sceneCenter->addEllipse(xCor-4,yCor-4,imgW+7,imgH+7,blackpen,redBrush);
```

Now i want to add hoverEnterEvent so every time i drag my mouse to these ellipse it would do something, so i made this class:

```
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QMessageBox>

class myEllipse : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{
public:
    myEllipse(QGraphicsEllipseItem* parent);
    void hoverEnterEvent(int index);
};

#endif // MYELLIPSE_H

#include "myellipse.h"

myEllipse::myEllipse(QGraphicsEllipseItem* parent):QGraphicsEllipseItem(parent){
    setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
}


void myEllipse::hoverEnterEvent(int index){
    QMessageBox q;
    q.setText("hello");
    q.exec();
}
```

I want to replace QGraphicsEllipseItem by the object created by the class above. How do i do this?

Comment: Loot at [QGraphicsScene::addItem(QGraphicsItem*)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addItem)

Comment: @jbh I know how to add normal QGraphicsItem. I just don't know how to add the inherit one. I tried to add like normal but it said invalid conversion QGraphicsEllipseItem* to myEllipse*.

Comment: `addEllipse` is just a shorthand. Set the properties you want on your elipse item (position, brush, etc), then add it to your scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you're doing this: -

```
QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse;
ellipse = sceneCenter->addEllipse(xCor-4,yCor-4,imgW+7,imgH+7,blackpen,redBrush);
```

If you create an instance of your new class first, you can then add it afterwards and set its position and other properties:-

```
myEllipse * ellipse = new myEllipse(parent);
sceneCenter->addItem(ellipse);

ellipse->setRect(xCor-4,yCor-4,imgW+7,imgH+7);
ellipse->setPen(blackpen);
ellipse->setBrush(redBrush);
```

Comment: how do i set the width and height of this ellipse? I can't find it in the documentation. And the hoverEnterEvent does not work either. :(

Comment: The call to setRect sets the item's rectangle, which includes width and height.

Comment: ok! It works like charm. However the hoverEnterEvent still does not work. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Note that the signature for the hover event does not take an int as its argument, but is void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent * event) - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#hoverEnterEvent

Comment: You're a savior. Thank you so much. Just test and it flawlessly works.